# Some confusion in differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right),  & \text{if }x \neq 0 \\
0, & \text{if }x=0
\end{cases}$$

1) Compute $f'(0)$.

2) Is $f'(x)$ a continuous function? Justify the answer.

I am quite confused on this. How should I do?

Comment: For evaluating $f'(0)$, you may want to use the First Principle. For $x\neq 0$, simply evaluate $f'(x)$ as you might normally.

Answer (score 3):

To compute $f'(0)$, you won't be able to simply compute $f'(x)$ from the non-zero formula, and then plug in $0$, or even take a limit as $x\to 0$. (Doing that would be *assuming* the derivative is continuous.) Instead, you have to go back to the definition of a derivative at a point.

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$

This limit can be calculated, because we know that $f(0)=0$, so it simplifies to:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{h^2}\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} h\cos\left(\frac{1}{h^2}\right)$$

This expression inside the last limit is bounded between $h$ and $-h$ as $h\to 0$, so we can evaluate its limit by the Squeeze Theorem.

That takes care of $f'(0)$. To address the continuity of $f'$, you can apply differentiation rules to find $f'(x)$ when $x\ne 0$, and then see whether the limit of the resulting expression exists, and matches your answer from the first part.

Comment: it helps a lot. Thank you very much!!